# Местоположение текста в navbar

Tags: bootstrap, flask

У меня есть bootstrap navbar и мне нужно в правой его части сделать Logout, но как мне его туда перенести? Через text-align не работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Принеси сюда код.

Comment: Добавить `pull-right` class